# Using regex split function python to split when not surrounded by integers

Tags: python, regex, string, split

For example, I have a string containing the following

```
Input:    
blah 3.16591128 blah.something blah. blah blah.3 3.blah
```

I want to split it with respect to "." & " " in such a way that I get number as a whole and rest everything gets split.

```
Output:    
3.16591128, blah, something, blah, blah, blah, 3, blah, 3, blah
```

I know how to split both "." as well as " " using

```
re.split("\.| ", str)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Try [`r'(?:(?<!\d(?=\.\d))\.|\s)+'`](https://regex101.com/r/hYhlXD/1).

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew this worked. Could you please also explain a little bit about whats going in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that meets your requirements is

```
r'(?:(?<!\d(?=\.\d))\.|\s)+'
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYhlXD/1)

It matches one or more consecutive repetitions (due to the `+` quantified non-capturing group `(?:...)+`) of:

- `(?<!\d(?=\.\d))\.` - a dot (`\.`) that is not preceded with a digit that is followed with a `.` and another digit (due to the negative lookahead `(?=\.\d)` inside the positive lookbehind)
- `|` - or
- `\s` - a whitespace.